# i have the values in variable but cannot update in MySql db

Tags: php, mysql

for admin panel i have made a table with delete, edit and add option with each row, every thing is working perfect except the execution of update query, uptil now have shown text to be edit in its form, and delivered the edit values to the next page which i have verified by usin echo(). My code is as following
    
    
    
    update.php

```
<head>

<?php   
// 1. Create a database connection
// 2. Select a database to use 
include('connect.php');
?>
<?php
// 3. Perform database query          
$id=$_SESSION['id'];       
$author=$_GET['author'];
$quotation=$_GET['quote'];

//below code is to check
echo $id . "<br>". $author . "<br>". $quotation ."<br>";
//4. update query
$query = "UPDATE 'quotations' SET 
'author' = '$author',
'quotation' = '$quotation', 
WHERE 'id' = '$id'";
mysql_query($query);
// test to see if the update occurred
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
// Success!
echo "The page was successfully updated."; 
} else {
echo "The page could not be updated.";
}
?>
<?php
 // 5. Close connection
 mysql_close($connection);
session_destroy();
//header("Location: Admin.php");   commented just to observe the output.

?>
</body>
</html>
```

by echo before query i`m getting my edit values which means there is no issue with the form, even db connected but no updates. Any suggession in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: **NOTE:** Your code is vulnurable to [***SQL-Injection***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I have a feeling it's that same vulnerability that's causing the issue with the update itself.  If any of those variables contain a single-quote it'll fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL-escape your variables! Or better yet: use the mysqli/PDO prepared statements.

Additionally, your tablename is wrapped in single-quotes, and there is a stray comma before your `WHERE` clause. Use backquotes instead (or no quotes at all should be fine for that table name.)

```
$query = "UPDATE `quotations` SET 
'author' = '$author',
'quotation' = '$quotation'
WHERE 'id' = '$id'";
```

MySQLi: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

MySQLi Prepared Statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

PDO Prepared Statement method: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Oh, thanks for the catch duskwuff. *sigh* Syntax will be the death of us all.

Comment: thanks for the answers; i tried the code with removing the syntax errors that you mentioned but stil doesn`t work, i think i must search for that mysqli/PDO statements.......

Comment: Added the MySQLi and PDO manual links to the answer.  These are replacements to all the `mysql_*` functions. The `mysql_*` functions will be removed in a later version of php.  If `pdo` and `mysqli`, for some reason, are not available in your php installation, run your `$author` and `$quote` variables through [mysql_real_escape_string](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

Is the id attribute in the database a numeric field? If so, you shouldn't be adding the single quotes in the `UPDATE` string.

```
$query = "UPDATE 'quotations' SET 
'author' = '$author',
'quotation' = '$quotation', 
WHERE 'id' = $id"
```